# C# How do I handle a one time startup condition for a form if the form is generated new each time?

Tags: c#, forms, boolean, startup

I have `form A`, which opens `form B` after an event then hides itself. `Form B` generates conditions for `form A` then returns to `form A` and closes itself; however, due to conflict with code, I will have to generate `form A` anew lest I encounter a stackoverflow exception / my application not closing properly (due to `form A`, the main form, being hidden)

This has gotten a bit confusing, essentially I've already solved this by declaring the main form as new each time, however, I wish to be able to handle first time startup events like those tutorial messages for certain applications. Without the overhead of having to create a log to store my boolean, how will I detect if it's the first time the form is opened?

Normally I would:

```
Event(){
  bool startup;
  if (startup = true) {
  startup = false;
  return;
  }
  //Rest of code
}
```

However, since the form is generated new each time, this will always remain true.

Here's the code:

Form A variables:

```
 Account AccountForm = new Account();
```

Button event:

```
        AccountForm.QR = this;
        this.Hide();
        AccountForm.ShowDialog();
```

Form B:

```
public Form QR { get; set; }
```

Button event:

```
    QR = new QueryRefiner();
    this.QR.Show();
    this.Close();
```

This is all of it I think. I take the new declaration out of QR, and I would receive a StackOverflow exception. I guess I should have created a new question for this, but there it is. (I think i'm on the timer still)

Comment: Why can you not just show the original Form A again? You said something about a stack overflow, but show no code that would cause that

Comment: @RufusL, I do, but as I said, the boolean would remain true. If you mean, to simply show the form rather than creating it new I would encounter some Stackoverflow exception which was only solved by declaring a new form A. EDIT: I'm not sure if it's worth it to copy the whole code, but as far as i've analyzed, the exception is caused by the first form remaining hidden after opening the second form and opening the first form again. Anyway, I'll see if I can post the code pertaining to the question.

Comment: You should not get a stack overflow by calling Form.Show(), unless there is some circular reference going on, which you have not shown.

Comment: I agree with @RufusL. You must have some problem in your code that maybe if creating some loop of creating/showing both forms that cause that StackOverflow

Comment: Your original problems of stack-overflow or application not closing are solvable using means other than creating a new main form each time. And it sounds like doing so would solve this problem. If you insist on not fixing those, then this can be addressed in a variety of other ways, all involving some sort of static or longer-lived state representation. There are _many_ different ways to approach it though, making the question too broad. You need to work harder to narrow the question. Provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, tell us what that does, and what you want instead.

Comment: @RufusL, I've updated the code above, however, I must apologize, I'd forgotten that the reason I wanted to create a new form A each time was to make use of the Form_Shown event which would basically, using the criteria from form B, create a database of some sort. Naturally, having not been to form B yet, there is no initial criteria for form A, so that was why I wanted a start up sort of condition.

Comment: I think you have a design problem there. Why you need to create a database in `FormShown()`? Just call a public method in your  `FormA` from your `FormB` after creating or showing the `FormA`

Comment: @Pikoh Yes, it may be a design problem afterall, but those aren't the type of questions I can ask on StackOverflow. I actually have a similar code to use as the answer Rufus posted, here's how it goes: `if(Application.OpenForms[FormB.Name] == null)` `FormB.Show();` etc. Though, this was for putting focus on FormB if it was present. I'lll punch in your code and see if I can get rid of that exception. You do have an interesting solution, to advance the variable if it is created from formB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,an easy solution is to make a new constructor in your `FormA` to get a parameter indicating that it is created from `FormB`, something like:

```
public FormA(bool byFormB)
{
    if (byFormB)
    {
        //do what you have to do when it's created from FormB
    }
}
```

And just create it like this from `FormB`: `FormA frm=new FormA(true);`

Anyway, I would not create a new `FormA` each time, just hide/show it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it: Expose a public property in your `FormB` that holds a reference to a `FormA`. When you create an instance of `FormB` from `FormA`, set the reference to point to `FormA`. Then, in the `Form_Closing()` event of `FormB`, show the `FormA`.

You can also expose public properties and/or methods on your `FormA` so that `FormB` can pass on any information it gathered back to `FormA` before it exits:

```
public partial class FormB : Form
{
    public FormA formToShowOnClose { get; set; }

    private void FormB_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (formToShowOnClose != null)
        {
            formToShowOnClose.TableName = txtTableName.txt;
            formToShowOnClose.LoadData();
            formToShowOnClose.Show();
        }
    }

    // Other form B code here...
}

public partial class FormA : Form
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        // Do something with TableName here
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formB = new FormB();
        formB.formToShowOnClose = this;
        this.Hide();
        formB.Show();
    }

    // Other form A code here...
}
```

Comment: How do I replicate a form.Shown() event? In my current code, the reason I persisted on creating a new main form each time was so I could fire an event each time the formB happened to show formA. How can I handle this using your code? I presume, I would add it to the closing event?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What do you plan on doing in the `Shown()` event? There may be a better solution here...

Comment: Yes, there might be. Shown event contains a standard select * from database method, the table in particular is selected from FormB. So, there would be something like FormB.Table, the table I will open. The design is such that I can freely switch between forms, select a table from FormB then view it in FormA. The shown event facillitates it what I needed, so something similar would be great.

Comment: You can expose public properties on your `FormA`, and set them from `FormB`, and/or create public methods on `FormA` and call them from `FormB`. I updated my example with samples of setting a public property and calling a public method on FormA from FormB.

Comment: So LoadData can be used as if it were being triggered while the main form is active? This is pretty useful. I've done similar things in Unity 5, I was wondering if it was applicable here, though get/set's always confuse me. How are specific controls handled under this? Say I have a datagridview on FormA; with this, I can write data from FormB directly into it?

Comment: Hmmm, it isn't working, but it also isn't throwing any errors, so I'm not sure what I am missing, I'll make a new thread so we can answer on that tomorrow, this is getting a bit lengthy.