# C# Exposing public methods/properties on one form then calling them from another

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, properties

Here is the thread where it was suggested [Rufus' Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446753/c-sharp-how-do-i-handle-a-one-time-startup-condition-for-a-form-if-the-form-is-g/43447026?noredirect=1#comment73951644_43447026), but I can't seem to call Formtoshowonclosing because I'm only receiving a null pointer exception, am I right in thinking that the first form, `QR` is not being read? or are the methods from form QR unable to be read? It's not throwing any other errors.

Legend: Form A = QR, is loaded first, then is hidden. Form B = Account, is loaded next, where the user selects criteria for a database. Button is pressed, Account is closed and QR is shown, methods of QR are triggered from Account upon closing and database is loaded.

Here is what I've got so far, tell me what I seem to be missing.

Exposed properties on QR:

```
    public string BUName { get; set; }
    public string DOCUName { get; set; }
```

on public void QR()

```
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Hide();
            Account AccountForms = new Account();
            AccountForms.FormToShowOnClose = this;
            AccountForm.ShowDialog();
```

LoadData (Loads criteria from Account in preparation for Refresher(), which is a standard Select * from [Table]):

```
    public void LoadData()
    {
        txtBUnow.Text = BUName;
        txtDOCUnow.Text = DOCUName;
        if (BUName != "")
        {
            int BUtoQRConv = Convert.ToInt32(BUName);
            theDictionary = new DictionaryInit();
            DictionaryFindTable(BUtoQRConv, theDictionary.BUtoQRs);
            Refresher();
        }
    }
```

Account form:

```
    public static string passedBU;
    public static string passedDOCU;
    public QueryRefiner FormToShowOnClose { get; set; }
```

Button press:

```
        passedBU = lblBUitem.Text;
        passedDOCU = lblDOCUitem.Text;
        this.Close();
```

On Form closing:

```
    private void Account_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormToShowOnClose != null)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(passedBU + "!");
        FormToShowOnClose.BUName = passedBU;
        FormToShowOnClose.DOCUName = passedDOCU;
        FormToShowOnClose.LoadData();
        FormToShowOnClose.Show();
        }
    }
```

As it stands, there are no compiler errors, when it runs, the if statement doesn't seem to be triggering, and when extracted from the if statement, I do hit a nullpointer exception at FormToShowonClose.
Any idea what I might be missing here? QR is already initialized as far as I can tell, just hidden.

Comment: You assume the dialog will only ever close when the user presses the button.  This is not the case, lots more reasons for it to close.  Like the user clicking the close button, the dialog's owner window closing, calling Hide() on a dialog window, other code calling Application.Exit(), the operating system restarting and probably some more I did not think of.  Kaboom, the *passed* variables are null.  This is just not the right way to use a dialog, the return value of ShowDialog() is critical and the dialog should never know anything about another window.

Comment: Hmmm, yes I did consider the possibility of the Data ending in limbo through this method, however, the selection merely handles data that will appear on the view. If any data is lost, it will only affect the view, and nothing more. Effectively, when the user enters FormB into FormA, their progress is essentially restarted. Though this is definitely something everyone should consider when handling data that can be lost in transit. What would your suggestion be though? Handle all the business data on the main window? @HansPassant

Answer (score 1):

Move this code to Load event handler of QR Form:

```
this.Hide();
Account AccountForms = new Account();
AccountForms.FormToShowOnClose = this;
AccountForm.ShowDialog();
```